# When extending a base.html , is the <!DOCTYPE html> tag passed on aswell?

Tags: html, django, extends, doctype

The title says it all.

Is the doctype of: (base.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Passed on to (home.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Or do I need to declare the doctype in all of my documents?
like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to add `<!DOCTYPE html>` once you haved declared in the base.html when you are extending from it.